# Implementation of ln(x) for AVX, m256

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx

Is there a source code for a fast implementation of natural logarithm, for `__m256` type, for AVX?

There is [fmath](https://github.com/herumi/fmath/blob/master/fmath.hpp), but it only works for `__m128`

Comment: In glibc's libmvec?

Comment: @MarcGlisse could you please give the link to the source code

Comment: @Kari Strictly AVX, or AVX2? Single precision or double precision? Full ISO-C++ semantics and full accuracy, or reduced range and reduced accuracy?

Comment: try [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1):

Glibc has AVX[-512] SIMD `log` and `logf` implementations in the github repository: [`sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch;h=67eee6a867a52f4b59ce00b74624fb983ec98698;hb=refs/heads/master). It relies on a lot of support code, like polynomial coefficient data, macros, support functions, etc. Much of this is in the parent `fpu` directory.

GNU libc's license is LGPLv2, so you can dynamically link it from any software, but only copy the source into GPL-compatible projects.

[Agner Fog's Vector Class Library (VCL)](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) is now Apache-licensed, and also has some SIMD math functions.  It can be used with `__m256`, implicitly converting to/from its internal Vec8f type.